# Phabricator fail to send email

Tags: php, email, phabricator

I checked by using *./bin/mail list-outbound*, and found my mail in the queue
[php status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdhQ0.png)

[phabricator display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xlTS.png)

The following is my configuration:

```
metamta.mail-adapter
Current Value: "PhabricatorMailImplementationPHPMailerAdapter"

phpmailer.mailer
Current Value: "smtp"

phpmailer.smtp-host 
Cuttent Value:"My Mail server address"

phpmailer.smtp-port
Current Value: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 25 often enforces strict anti-spam rules which may be preventing your mail from working.  Does your mail server also offer authenticated access on port 587 which you can use with username and password instead?

Also your daemons are all showing as dead in the status you linked to. Maybe there is a problem with your phd configuration also, or you simply haven't started them?